# How can a random number be produced with decreasing odds (approaching zero) towards its upper boundary?

Tags: random, probability, pseudocode

I want a random number generator that almost never produces numbers that are near a given upper boundary.  The odds should drop linearly to 0 to the upper boundary.

This is possibly best suited as a math-only question, but I need it in code form (pseudo-code is fine, more specifically any C-based language) for my use, so I'm putting it here.

Comment: If you use `R`, you can draw a sample from, say, a lognormal distribution with `rlnorm(n, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1)`.

Comment: Exponentials and lognormals don't have a linear drop-off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a linear drop-off what you're describing is called a [triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_distribution) (or triangular) distribution.  Given `U`, a source of uniformly distributed random numbers on the range `[0,1)`, you can generate a triangle on the range `[a,b)` with its mode at `a` using:

```
def triangle(a,b)
    return a + (b-a)*(1 - sqrt(U))
end
```

This can be derived by writing the equation of a triangle for the specified range, scaling it so it has area 1 to make it a valid [density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function), integrating to get the [CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function), and using [inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

As an interesting aside, this will still work if `a >= b`.  For equality, you always get `a` (which makes sense if the range is zero).  Otherwise, you get a triangle which goes from `b` to `a` and has its mode at `a`.